# Why does spring Data REST ignore @javax.persistence.Version field while serializing an entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I looked into the code and noticed that org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module.$AssociationOmittingSerializerModifier.updateBuilder simply skips the version property.

For an item resource, version field is available in ETag header. 
But for a collection resource, we need the version id of items to honour optimistic locking while updating an item.

How can we get the version id for each item on a collection resource? Do we have any configuration to enable this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have a look at [Projections and Excerpts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts), it could help you. Anyway if you provide some example code, like your involved entities, the result you get and the result you want, we could elaborate some concrete solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the proper way to do this?

Comment: unfortunately not.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Getting access to the version is especially handy when a collection resource is returned and you want to update a single item in the collection.

I added an **alternatively named** 'getter' in the entity class that would return the version:

```
@Version
private long version;

public long getCurrentVersion()
{
  return version;
}
```

This causes the serialiser to create a `currentVersion` key in the returned JSON, I then pass its value as the value for the `If-Match` header.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually. For my purposes this works fine since I load the existing entity anyway before the update then copy the properties over from the REST entity.

```
    if (restEntity.version != null && restEntity.version != existing.version) {
        throw new OptimisticLockingFailureException("version number from REST doesn't match the database")
    }
```